# Local git repository not same as remote repository

Tags: git, github

My Github remote repository looks like this:

[image: github]

But when I `git clone`, my local repository looks like this:

[image: local]

How can I resolve this directory not being the same? The local directory is what I want it to be.

I tried:

```
git pull origin master
git merge origin master
git push origin master
```

but that did not resolve the problem.

Comment: could be that your os is not case sensitive and is therefore not capable of creating both `life` and `Life` folders

Comment: Are you on Windows? On NTFS, `Life` and `life` are exact the same - file system is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the naming of the folders.  The file system does not differ between different casing; so even if `Git` is able to keep track of the differences, it can’t communicate these difference to the file system.

Change names and try `git pull origin master` again. Best solution is to simply not use multiple folders with a conflicting name. Even on case-sensitive file systems, it will only make things more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are on osX (as the folder end name end by .app `Go2shell.app`). By default, osX file system is case insensitive. It is possible to make it sensitive but you have to format your partition and set the appropriate option ([more info](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20569?locale=en_US)). Then you will have to reinstall os X.

It also possible to avoid reinstall your operating system by making the sensitive partition on another drive and to work on this one.

Answer (score 1):

- `git config core.ignorecase false`
- `git commit -am "Suitable Message"`
- `git push origin master`
- `git pull origin master`

Once this is done. You should move `technology` and `Technology` into a folder. You can achieve this by `git mv Technology technology` or `git mv technology Technology`.